# How do I detect when my View has moved?

Tags: android

I have a View in my Activity.  I want to detect when it has moved around the screen due to any actions (user scrolls, relative views resize shifting contents, etc.).  This is meant to be in a library, so I can query the hierarchy, but I don't control it, nor can I modify it other than adding event listeners.

Is there any way to get this as an event, rather than polling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There **is** an event for this: `View.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener()`

```
final ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener mScrollChangedListener = ...;

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
  super.onAttachedToWindow();
  getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(mScrollChangedListener);
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
  super.onDetachedFromWindow();
  getViewTreeObserver().removeOnScrollChangedListener(mScrollChangedListener);
}
```

Source: Android Source Code (4.0), android.view.SurfaceView.java:205

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried listening for 'drag' events on your View?

Try implementing [onDragListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html), a good place to start understanding how to do that would be the Drag and Drop android tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't providing the events.  I'm not sure why, but it seems like this isn't exactly what that kind of event is for.

Comment: If you want to click a view and move it around, that is a 'drag', if it something that you can scroll, you can look at a onScrollListener. There is no listener for resizing so you might have to implement that listener by yourself.

Comment: What I'm looking for isn't a drag or a scroll event that I control.  My View sits inside of a third party View that can move my View around in any number of ways.  I want to know when I've been moved.  Because I don't own the parent view, I can't do any sort of override on any of it's behavior

Comment: okay, can u tell me what your View is exactly? and what are the ways that your View can be moved around?

Comment: Sorry, can't go into too much details at the moment.  Found the answer anyway, adding it here.